# Lua: get a substring

Tags: regex, lua, pattern-matching, substring

I have for example

```
str = "Beamer-Template!navigation symbols@\\texttt {navigation symbols}"
print(str:gsub('[^!|@%s]+@', ''))
```

which prints

```
Beamer-Template!navigation \texttt {navigation symbols}
```

but it should be

```
Beamer-Template!\texttt {navigation symbols}
```

How can I catch the space? 
Important is only the `foo@bar`. The pattern works fine for strings like

```
str="foo@bar!baz@foobar!nice|crazy"
-> bar!foobar!nice|crazy
```

but not with an additional space

```
str="foo@bar!baz baz@foobar!nice|crazy"
-> bar!baz foobar!nice|crazy
```

which should be `bar!foobar!nice|crazy`

Comment: Remove `%s` from the pattern

Comment: uhh, that was simple ... Please give it as an answer, then the question isn't unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `makeindex` entries it might be useful to use an LPEG grammar.  This way you can split at the separators and even perform semantic actions, depending on the matched field.

```
local lpeg = assert(require"lpeg")
local C, S = lpeg.C, lpeg.S

local sep = S("@!|")
local str = C((1 - sep)^0)

local idx = str * ( "@" * str / function(match) return "@" .. match end
                  + "!" * str / function(match) return "!" .. match end
                  + "|" * str / function(match) return "|" .. match end)^0

print(idx:match("hello!world@foo|bar"))
```

```
$ lua test.lua 
hello   !world  @foo    |bar
```

---

Answer to the comment:  Collecting the matches in a table.  The matches are collected according to their prefix.

```
local lpeg = assert(require"lpeg")
local C, Ct, S = lpeg.C, lpeg.Ct, lpeg.S

local sep = S("@!|")
local str = C((1 - sep)^0)

local match = function(expr)
    local prefix = function(prefix)
        return function(match)
            return prefix .. match
        end
    end

    local idx = str * ( "@" * str / prefix("@")
                      + "!" * str / prefix("!")
                      + "|" * str / prefix("|"))^0

    return Ct(idx):match(expr)
end

for _, str in ipairs{
    "hello!world@foo|bar",
    "foo@bar!baz baz@foobar!nice|crazy",
    "foo@bar!baz@foobar!nice|crazy",
    "Beamer-Template!navigation symbols@\\texttt {navigation symbols}"
} do
    local t = match(str)
    print(table.concat(t," "))
end
```

```
$ lua test.lua 
hello !world @foo |bar
foo @bar !baz baz @foobar !nice |crazy
foo @bar !baz @foobar !nice |crazy
Beamer-Template !navigation symbols @\texttt {navigation symbols}
```

Comment: how can I get the values in a table?

Comment: @Herbert Do you mean adding the captured values to a table (`table.insert(t, "@foo")`) or using the matches to index a table (`return t["@foo"]`)?

Comment: the first one: a table collecting all matches should be returned

Comment: I can do it with several `select(i,..)` but that's a bit odd

Comment: thanks. But too complicated ... maybe that it wasn't clear enough: `foo@bar!baz@foobar!nice|crazy` should return `t={foo, @bar, !baz,@foobar, !nice, |crazy}`

Comment: But no problem, I changed your code .. works fine now